# Converting Struts2 web app to Angular6

Tags: angular, struts2

We have large multiple page application in Struts2 which we decided to convert into  Angular6 SPA. We want for some time have mixed web application. New pages write in angular. Existing pages we gradually rewrite. But in this rewriting process web must work. I try to find some guidelines or approaches but I found only for AngularJS ([Converting your web app to Single-Page with AngularJS](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/22859/Converting-your-web-app-to-Single-Page-with-AngularJS.html)). This article describes exactly what we need. But for AngularJS. Have anybody experiencies with this issue? Any useful links, examples? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is OT for SO. It's not clear what you actually want help with--adding Angular doesn't affect anything on the back end, e.g., the Angular app is just a JS bundle you ship to the client, which will presumably consume new or existing APIs from the back end. Your SPA routing would be handled internally by Angular, and if you want to have a pseudo-SPA app, e.g., some routes handled by Angular, some by S2, then it's less of an SPA and more of a "we'll use Angular on some of these pages, but they're isolated from other Angular pages".

Comment: I want help with find the right way to migrate our web to angular. We are not able to rewrite it at once. It could be a solution where some pages is rendered by angular and some by S2? Use routing from angular and S2 together (how give control each other and share e.g. loged user context). Or there could be only angular routing and rewrite all S2 views to angular - this bring too much work in one time. At the end we wat to have full SPA. But for some time we probably need as you wrote "pseudo-SPA app". But not completely isolated. We need share some data (loged user etc.) Is it possible?